My Godot 4 2D game is running badly on HTML5 on some PCs
I'm using Godot 4.2.1 and my game is a pretty simple top down shooter. I tried exporting to HTML5 on Itch.io and the game runs fine on certain PCs but not others ?...
when running the game on my computer with this CPU "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz 3.30 GHz" and 8 GB ram and no graphic card:

game.exe runs completely fine

game on HTML5 runs completely fine


when running the game on my non gaming laptop with this CPU "11th gen intel(r) core(tm) i5-1135g7 @ 2.40ghz 2.42 ghz" and 8 GB ram and no graphic card:

game.exe runs completely fine

game on HTML5 runs completely fine


when running the game on my laptop that's more suitable for gaming with this CPU "intel(R) core(TM)i7-5500U CPU@ 2.40 GHz 2.40 GHz" and 12 GB ram and this graphic card "Nvidia GeForce 940M"
:

game.exe runs fine but the graphics are blurry ?

game runs slowly when more objects appear on screen and graphics are also blurry


I'm not sure why exactly? I was expecting it to run best on my gaming laptop but it ran worse; the game is being rendered in compatibility mode too.
In Itch.io I have it set to be "Embeded in Page" and I manually set the size, for the frame options I turned on full screen and shared array buffer support.
Apparently HTML5 cares more about the CPU rather than the graphics card so I'm guessing that older CPUs struggle to run it more?
Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something about HTML5, I'm still new to this. What can I do to make the game run well on all devices?
I tried switching from Firefox to chrome but now the game doesn't even start on HTML5 because some sort of .pck file seems to be missing.

The best advice I can give is to update your drivers. This sounds like a video card problem. Godot 4.x uses the Vulkan graphics API, which is an open standard. Your drivers may not be up to date, and this may be causing your problem. Since it runs fine on worse specs, it is not your game, the way you exported, or the Godot engine itself.
You can check out the NVIDIA Vulkan drivers here.
